# Query for golf score tracking db in Libre Base

Tags: libreoffice-base

Here's where I need help; My sql skills only take me so far.

I want to assign a set of values to the "Hole 1 Delta" value based on the following criterion:

- If Delta is =  -2 (which is an eagle) I want to assign 6 points to a field called "Hole 1 Points"
- If Delta is = -1 (which is a birdie) I want to assign 4 points to a field called "Hole 1 Points"
- If Delta is = 0 (which is a par) I want to assign 2 points to a field called "Hole 1 Points"
- If Delta is = +1 (which is a bogie) I want to assign 1 point to a field called "Hole 1 Points"
- If Delta is >+1 zero points get assigned.

I have a lookup table with the values but my sql skills can't figure out how to utilize. Table is called Score_Lookup

I tried building a query but I can't figure out how to do nested IF to get my values. Here's my sql;

```
SELECT "Date", "Course Name", "Hole 1 Delta", "Hole 1 Delta" + 2 AS "Hole 1 Points"
FROM "Points_Calc"
WHERE "Hole 1 Delta" = 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds like this is an SQL question, not specifically LO Base. So, what engine are you using? Perhaps HSQLDB 1.8 with Embedded setup (zipped into the .odb file). If you're not sure, search online for how to find out. Adding a tag for the engine should get more views of people who can answer correctly.